# float type Buffer contents lost after creating object C++

Tags: c++, buffer, typedef

I have a class that contains a float type buffer which points to an array of RGB values. The buffer is created and stored properly but when I return the instance of this class throught a function to the **main()** the memory of the buffer is unreadable. Here is the **initial class**:

```
namespace imaging
{
    typedef float component_t;

    class Image
    {
        protected:
            component_t * buffer;
            unsigned int width, height;
        public:
            Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const component_t * data_ptr) {
            this->width = width;
            this->height = height;
            this->setData(data_ptr);
            this->buffer = const_cast<component_t *>(data_ptr);
        }

        component_t getRedValPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const {
            int pos = x * this->width * 3;
            component_t red;
            red = this->buffer[pos];
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

To create an instance of this class I use a **readImage(char* filepath)** method  that after loading the data has this **return** statement:

```
return &Image(width, height, buffer);
```

Here is the code in the **main()** function:

```
Image* image = readIamge(filepath);
int width = image->getWidth(); //retrieves it correctly
int height = image->getHeight(); //retrieves it correctly
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        cout << image->getRedValPixel(i,j);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return &Image(width, height, buffer);` is almost certainly wrong. You'll be returning a pointer to a temporary object that will be destroyed before the functions ends. Please (re-)read anything you have on pointers.

Comment: @Yexo I see. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return &Image(width, height, buffer); will return the address of locally created object in the stack, which will be destroyed just after loosing the scope( i.e. the return statement ).

Solution is to allocate the Image object in heap.
E.g.

```
main()
{
....
Image* image = NULL;
readImage(filepath, image );
int width = image->getWidth(); //retrieves it correctly
int height = image->getHeight(); //retrieves it correctly
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        cout << image->getRedValPixel(i,j);
    }
}
delete image;
image = NULL
...
}


void readImage(char* filepath, Image* o_pBuffer ) 
{
   .....
   o_pBuffer = new Image(width, height, buffer);
   return o_pBuffer;
}
```

or

```
main()
{
....
Image* image = NULL;
image = readImage(filepath );
int width = image->getWidth(); //retrieves it correctly
int height = image->getHeight(); //retrieves it correctly
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        cout << image->getRedValPixel(i,j);
    }
}
delete image;
image = NULL
...
}


Image* readImage(char* filepath ) 
{
   .....
   Image* o_pBuffer = new Image(width, height, buffer);
   return o_pBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a closer look at your return statement:

```
return &Image(width, height, buffer);
```

What happens when you do `Image(...)` is that a *temporary* object is created. This temporary object will be destructed once the expression it is in is over. You then return a pointer to this temporary object, an object which will then promptly disappear and leave you with a pointer to a non-existing object. Attempting to dereference this pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The data you read from the file *might* still be in memory somewhere, but it's not available from the pointer you returned.

I suggest you instead return the object *by value* and study things like *move semantics*, *move constructors* and [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I also suggest you not only copy the pointer to the actual data for the object, but copy the actual data itself (a *deep copy*).

Comment: @i_ll_be_back I suggest you *don't* return a pointer, but return by value instead. In modern C++ there's seldom any need to use pointers these days. And if you really need pointers (mostly for polymorphism) then use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers).

Comment: @i_ll_be_back Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @SimonKraemer I have to follow an interface and this method should return the pointer to this object. What if I would overload the & operator to pass the temporary data of the buffer to the returned object and then delete the temporary one

Comment: @i_ll_be_back Then use `new` to create a new object, and return the pointer that `new` gives you.

Comment: @i_ll_be_back The interface doesn't look right. If you really need to return a pointer use `return new Image(width, height, buffer);`. But keep in mind that you have to manage the life time of the object now by yourself. So you need to either call `delete` on the returned pointer after using it or pass it to a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Image>` that will delete the data for you.